# Google Compute Engine denying access to ip address

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster running on GCE. Someone is using bots to create a lot of requests on my server and I don't know how to block him. I could do it from within the application but that will eat a lot more resources as compared to a more elegant solution such as a firewall rule.

I tried adding such a firewall rule without any positive results:
[image]

I would probably drop it if I was using the Nginx loadbalancer but I'm using their own loadbalancer and I can't mangle with that.

So...how does one ban a request based on source ip address in GCE/kubernetes?

Comment: You mention you are using a load balancer- is it a network load balancer or a HTTP(s) load balancer? Also, where are you seeing the traffic from that IP address? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run nginx behind the GCE ingress and reject IPs based on the X-Forwarded-FOR header [github] (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/whitelist)